# How to create a global object class in Objective-c available to all other classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create some type of object or class that stores a whole bunch of variables I get from a server at one point in my application. I would then like to make this object or class available to the whole project so that I can make use or even update the variables of this object or class.

I have no idea where to start with this as I am not even sure if it's possible.

Currently the problem I am facing is that I have all of these objects passing data around different classes and I'm pretty much nesting these objects and its become very inefficient to keep track of this code. However if I had some type of class that I could just access from anywhere with all of the values up to date this would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: All you need to do is make a class that either has A) A static shared object (similar to `NSFileManager`, etc) or B) static methods.  Those are methods that start with a `+` instead of a `-`.

Comment: You're looking for a `singleton`.  There are plenty of examples and what you're looking for will be easy to find with that new search keyword.

Comment: The one thing im really confused by is this. Say I create this objectZ in Class A I then go to class B how can i find or access objectZ without creating a new instance of it self? or is that covered in singletons

Comment: That is what a singleton does so well. When calling the static method [SharedClass sharedHelper] in my example below, the dispatch_once will only allow one object to be instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an object that you access through this:

```
+ (MySingleton *)sharedMySingleton
{
  static dispatch_once_t shared_initialized;
  static MySingleton *shared_instance = nil;

  dispatch_once(&shared_initialized, ^ {
    shared_instance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
  });

  return shared_instance;
}
```

As the comments said it is a singleton pattern. The first time you access your object it is created, then each subsequent time you get the same object when you call `[MySingleton sharedMySingleton];`

Comment: you both get marks however this one recives the tick.. sorry i cant give two ticks LOL thanks im going to go implement this now.

Answer (score 2):

A singleton is the way to go.

```
+(SharedClass *) sharedHelper {
    static sharedClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedInstance = [sharedClass alloc];
        sharedInstance = [sharedInstance init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a data container singleton. A singleton is an object that gets created once and only once during the life of the project. It has a class method that lets you request the object.

Search on "Cocoa singleton design pattern" to find more about it.

You might have a class MyDataObject, and it might have a class method sharedDataObject. The contents of the .m file might look like this:

```
@implementation MyDataObject
static _sharedDataObject;

+(MyDataObject) sharedDataObject
{
  if (!_sharedDataObject)
    _sharedDataObject = [[MyDataObject alloc] init];
  return _sharedDataObject;
}

@end
```

Then you just add properties to the header of the data object as needed. Anywhere you need it, #import the header for the data object in your other classes, and then use code like this:

```
//To store a value to a property in the shared data object:
[MyDataObject sharedDataObject].someProperty = someValue;

//To fetch a value:
someValue = [MyDataObject sharedDataObject].someProperty;
```

If you need the contents of your shared data object to persist, you can make the shared data object conform to NSCoding, and then save its contents to a file when your app shifts to the background, and load its contents from a file on launch.

Note that Cocoa and Cocoa touch use a lot of singleton objects. NSUserDefaults is a singleton, and so is NSFileManager. The tip-off for a singleton is the use of a class method to return a single object. Often in Apple's frameworks the class method's name will start with "shared" or "default"

Comment: Oh phooie. I took too long to compose my message, and others beat me to it. The other posters even included the thread-safe use of dispatch_once. See their posts.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is a good pattern for create one singleton object in your program, for the objects that does not interact with other singletons. 
If you have many singleton objects with complexity interaction, you should have more control of creation of  your objects. 
You can use your AppDelegate, and create Singletons in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching as fields of your AppDelegate.
Or you can create one Singleton object, that will contain other objects and will create other objects with necessary logic.